# Best Practices, same functionality from 1 method and also from 2 methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, coding-style, application-design

I have following scenario.
Some people use approach 1 and some use approach 2.
Both approaches have same functionality lock or unlock news against news id in news table.
what you suggest,which one is better and why?

***Note:I use void return type instead of bool for simplicity so please ignore this***

**Approach 1:**

```
public void LockNews(long newId)
{
 ......
}

public void UnlockNews(long newId)
{
 ...
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
public void LockUnlockNews(long newId,bool Islock)
{
 ......
}
```

Comment: lock is fag in database,you can say this news is locked for review

Comment: For me it would depend on the logic, if there's a lot of logic you don't want to be replicating it in both functions. Then you could also implemented approach 2, make it private and then call it from each subsequent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 1, for me, because IMHO a method should represent a single operation. In the interest of writing testable code or any form of automated testing, it would maintain a clear separation and make a lot more sense.

Approach 2 is leaning towards a "does everything" operation, which IMHO should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Approach 1. It makes it clear what is going on. If you use approach 2 and call

```
LockUnlockNews(42, true);
```

It is not immediately clear whether this is a lock or an unlock.
Just to throw some fuel on the fire: If you changed the bool to an enum or a const, then my argument is null and void.

```
LockUnlockNews(42, LOCK);
```

is just as clear as

```
LockNews(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

First approach.

Your method is a **Command** and should be as explicit as possible. I would even ask you why someone but News itself know how to lock/unlock? For me News should be responsible for it:

```
var news = GetNewsSomehow(newsId);
news.Lock();
news.Unlock();
```

Makes more sense, doesn't it? :) You clearly see what your objects are and what behaviors they have. This is what is called *encapsulation* in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I combine both approaches generally like below:

**Public methods** provide *clear interface* and are *more testable*:

```
public void LockNews(long newId)
{
    LockUnlockNews(newId, true);
}

public void UnlockNews(long newId)
{
    LockUnlockNews(newId, false);
}
```

**Private method** *does actual business* and *increases modularity* managing things from one location:

```
private void LockUnlockNews(long newId,bool Islock)
{
    ......
}
```